# Phonegap: My Javascript code works on browsers but it doesn't work on Android emulator or device

Tags: javascript, android, jquery-mobile, checkbox, cordova

I'm trying to make an Android App using phonegap and JQuery Mobile.

I have a div that shows a value. That value is changed whenever I click on the checkbox by adding or subtracting the div's value from the labels value

This is my index file which I install on the Android Device.

```
<head>
 <script>
  function inputData(idVar)
 {
 var myId;
 myId = document.getElementById(idVar).getAttribute("value");
 var myTag = document.getElementById(idVar);

 var mymyTag = myTag.querySelectorAll(".ui-btn-text");
 var myData = mymyTag[0].innerHTML;
 var myDataParsed = parseInt(myData);
if (document.getElementById(myId).checked==false)
 {
 myDataPrased =  myDataParsed+parseInt(document.getElementById("input_label").innerHTML);
 document.getElementById("input_label").innerHTML=myDataPrased;
 }
 else
 {
 var myResult
 var myOldData = parseInt(document.getElementById("input_label").innerHTML);
 myResult = myOldData-myDataParsed;
 document.getElementById("input_label").innerHTML=myResult;  
 }
 }

  </script>
  </head>

<body>
<div data-role="page" id="input">
<div data-role="header"></div>
  <div data-role="content">

    <div data-role='fieldcontain' align="center">
    <fieldset data-role='controlgroup' id="in">
    </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div id="input_label">0</div>
     <a href="#data" data-role="button" data-inline="true">Back</a>
</div>
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
    <h4>Page Footer</h4>
</div>
```

The Checkboxes are generated from a php page. and insearted in

```
 <fieldset data-role='controlgroup' id="in">
```

The function "inputData" is called when I click the label (In JQuery Mobile the label tag seems to cover the CheckBox, so when I think I'm clicking the checkbox, I'm actually clicking on the label and then it will generate an event that will trigger the Checkbox)

the function will receive the ID of the label. Then using it, I get the ID of CheckBox by extracting it from the "value" attribute of the label tag, so I can use it to check for the if the CheckBox is checked or not.

This code runs perfectly on a Web Browser like FireFox. But it doesn't run it when I install it on Android Device using Eclipse. No matter how I click on the Checkbox. the value of the div doesn't change.

Comment: What do you mean "the checkboxes are generated form a php page"? Is this a .php page?

Comment: This is an Index.Html file. It is not the php file that generates the Checkboxes. I use jquery $post method to connect to server and load those checkboxes whenever I reload the page.

The reason I use Ajax is because I need to load data along side along side with the checkboxes. Also, I have different scenarios. So the number of checkboxes will vary according to each one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix my issue by turning around. Instead of checking onclick events on the checkboxes and changing the value. I made a button called "calculate", which iterate on all the checkboxes and calculate the value of the checked ones. then editing the final value through onclick event on that button.

Thank you very much for everyone tried to help me, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

remember to load cordava file: `<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>`

Comment: Still no luck

What I actually can't understand is that I have many buttons on my project. And they all work on both browsers and Android Device just by adding the "onclick" attribute. I only have this issue with JQuery Mobile Checkboxes.

The "onclick" event on the label doesn't seem to work. I don't know why. It works only on Browsers like Chrome or FireFox when it comes to JQM Checkboxes. But not on the Android device.

Comment: The Android browser is pretty awful, it's like IE6. Probably what's happening is that it doesn't support onClick on label, or perhaps it doesn't support `myTag.querySelectorAll(".ui-btn-text");`.

Comment: I'm confused by "Android Browser". Do you mean the running browsers like chrome and firefox on Android or the layer that runs the phonegap on android?

Answer (score 0):

look at your config.xml file. Is there a line like

```
<access origin="http://127.0.0.1*" />
```

and the php script that does the checkbox-trick is not located at 127.0.0.1?
Then change that line to

```
<access origin="*" />
```

to get access to the remote host where your php file is located.

lg

fastrde